# How to test that a Child component renders based on the condition of the parent component's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My Parent component renders a `<Child1 />` component based on state `{ conditionMet : true }`.
How do I write a test that checks for the rendering of the child component, per se, rather than the rendering of a string within the component?  I'd like to avoid using `setTimeout()`.

Is this an issue with how I built the test?  Or, how I built the component?
Is there a known limitation or bug in Jest / Enzyme that prevents checking if a child component has rendered?

React: 16.6.3
Jest: 23.6.0
Enzyme: 3.7.0
Enzyme-adapter-react-16

Jest unit test for `ParentComponent`:

```
describe('ParentComponent', () => {
    test('renders Child1 component when conditionMet is true', () => { 

      const parentMount = mount(<ParentComponent />);

      const param1 = "expected value";
      const param2 = true;    
      parentMount.instance().checkCondition(param1, param2); // results in Parent's state 'conditionMet' === 'true'

      //This is not working - the length of the Child1 component is always 0
      expect(parentMount.find(Child1)).toHaveLength(1);

      //This alternate option passes, but it's not testing the rendering of the component!
      expect(parentMount.text()).toMatch('Expected string renders from Child1'); 

    });
  });
```

`ParentComponent.js`

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      conditionMet: false
    };
  }

  checkCondition = (param1, param2) => { 
  if (param1 === 'expected value' && param2 === true)
    {
       this.setState({conditionMet: true});
    } else {
       this.setState({conditionMet: false});
     }
     this.displayChildComponent();      
     }
  };

  displayChildComponent() {
    if (this.state.conditionMet) {
      return(
          <Child1 />
      )
    }
    else {
      return(
          <Child2 />
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent-container">
        {this.displayChildComponent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long solution, I guess. But it works.

Send a prop to children which is a function, call that function when the child is mounted.

Mount as,

```
<Clild1 sendConfirmation={this.receiveConfirmation.bind(this)} />
```

In parent:

```
receiveConfirmation(e, rendered_child){ this.setState({rendered_child}) }
```

In Child1:

```
componentDidMount(){this.props.sendConfirmation(1);}
```

Now if you can check the state of Parent, you can always check for this.state.rendered_child's value.